# Change scrollbar color in Iscroll

Tags: css, jquery-mobile, cordova, scrollbar

I am using ISCROLL with jquery mobile and phonegap... I am just trying to change the color of the scroll bar, I have tried adding this css but it´s not taking any effect.

```
        scrollbar-face-color: #ff0000;
        scrollbar-shadow-color: #ff0000;
        scrollbar-highlight-color:#ff0000;
        scrollbar-3dlight-color: #ff0000;
        scrollbar-darkshadow-color: #ff0000;
        scrollbar-track-color: #ff0000;
        scrollbar-arrow-color: #ff0000;
```

Does anyone of you know how to tweak this?

Answer (score 0):

Try targeting the Div like this:

```
.myScrollbarV *{
    background-color: #ff0000 !important;
}
```

Comment: can you confirm if the div class name is the same? As far as i know iScroll removes the default scroll bar and add custom divs -- open your code in browser and inspect element.

Comment: wait..!!! I tried it again and it worked... but it affected the page background and the scrollbar changed to red... I have a listview in jquery mobile. Where should I place the css class where it only affects the scrollbar element.

Comment: CSS i wrote should only effect scrollbar unless your HTML is broken, is there any way you can share you code?

Comment: This is the page containing the listview with the iscroll scrollbar applied. Where should I put the class you wrote:                                         <div data-role="page" id="page1">
 <div data-role="header">
   
 <h1>Items</h1> 
  
 </div>
 
 <div data-iscroll="" data-role="content"> 
 
 <ul data-role="listview" data-filter="true" data-filter-placeholder="Search Items...">
    <li>Item1</li>
 <li>Item2</li>
 <li>Item3</li>
 <li>Item4</li>
 <li>Item5</li>
 <li>Item6</li>
 <li>Item7</li>
 <li>Item8</li>
 <li>Item9</li>
 <li>Item10</li>
 <li>Item11</li>    
 </ul>
 
 </div>
 
</div>

Comment: Sorry... I don´t know how to set the html code block so it looks more readable

Comment: code looks fine, try to inspect element the scroll div (the actuall scrollbar not the div its applied on) & see what is its classname.

Comment: hello Imran.. did you have the chance to see?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58073/discussion-between-imran-bughio-and-xzibit).